# Restrict the user to focus an input

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular let assume I have the following input

```
<input class="cell" type="text" ng-readonly="true" ng-model="rowData.bgnInput">
```

Is it possible to restrict the user to focus this input. So no matter what i do the input should be never focused.
I want this because im using this input only to display data and im not using div because if its empty the div gets ugly

Answer (score 1):

I think you want readonly, not ng-readonly

```
<input class="cell" type="text" readonly ng-model="rowData.bgnInput">
```

Or if you don't want to even be able to select text, use disabled

```
<input class="cell" type="text" disabled ng-model="rowData.bgnInput">
```

Comment: LoL disabled forgot pure javascript directives :D